# Email List / Hosted Listserv / Google Groups / Yahoo Groups alternative

Tags: mailing-list

Need an alternative to Google Groups, now that the free GApps tier and all its apps are slowly bit-rotting.

I need a classic email mailing list functionality (a la listserv).

Ideally would support a custom domain, and allow users to unsubscribe at their own leisure. Nice to have would be add extra administrators outside the domain.

Comment: Self hosted or otherwise?

Comment: Preferably a saas, but self hosted is an option

Answer (score 3):

Please check us out, at https://groups.io. We've got all the functionality of Google Groups and Yahoo Groups, plus more. That means, in addition to being a fully functional mailing list server, we have the following:

- Ability to mute or follow specific threads
- Integration with other services, including: Github, Trello, Dropbox, Google Drive, Google Hangouts, and RSS feeds
- You can sync your member list with your Slack team
- Hashtag support
- Sub groups
- Fully integrated calendar, wiki, photo and file sections

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning what you mean by 'all the functionaliity' and adding a bit more. When you say "without the bitrot" what do you mean? Details would definately make the answer. If someone has to click through your site to see what you do, its not a good enough answer.

Comment: Given that it apparently your site, how about explaining the functionality and why you are better than Google Groups?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to list some of the features that make us better than Google groups.

Comment: Thanks @MarkFletcher. Looks like a good product but really overkill for the requirements. I just want a hosted mailing list for my football team. Needing a "Enterprise" license for what is essentially a DNS A-record is a bit steep also.

Comment: Usually if someone dings us, it's because we're **missing** a feature, not because we have too many of them. :-) In the next couple weeks, we'll be making subdomains available for free. Anyways, good luck with your search.

Answer (score 1):

[Gaggle Mail](http://gaggle.email) is a really simple group email offering.  It has:

- Custom domains
- Message archive
- Member subscribe

Answer (score 0):

[WP Mailster](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mailster/) is a plugin for WordPress

It enables one to run a classical mailing list, aka listserv, within a WordPress installation.

It allows for true two-way communication. That means that every email sent to a central email address is forwarded to the rest of the members of the list.

Users can self-subscribe through the WordPress site (with subscribe widgets) and/or subscribers can be managed by the admin in the backend as well.